# Files has invalid value - Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

While building my solution in VS 2013 I frequently get the following error in one or more projects:

```
Files has invalid value "�q�k=#4�ij�4�[i.x��w��zg
```

I performed a search on my solution directory and found that the culprit was the FileListAbsolute.txt file in the obj directory for the offending projects.

Deleting the obj directories temporarily solves the issue but it returns a few build later.

The contents of the file are sometimes complete garbage, other times it is perhaps 50% garbage - 50% valid file paths.

Any ideas what could be causing the FileListAbsolute to corrupt.

This started happening after moving the source to a new TFS collection and opening the solution using VS 2013. (It was previously a VS 2012 solution)

**Update:**
The FileListAbsolute.txt files are not in source control.

Comment: Is the file source controlled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something went wrong while mapping the collection to a local workspace.

The TFS collection mapping was for some reason invalid:

```
C:\Proj⩗㾆촌\Project1\...
```

While branches in the collection were mapped correctly:

```
C:\Projects\Project1\...
```

I removed the workspace mapping, deleted and recreated the local 'Projects' directory and remapped the workspace. This solved the issue.